# How to save a Javascript variable to a file in Django media folder?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a canvas where I draw a rectangle and save their coordinates.
The coordinates are saved in a Javascript dictionary.

Using the following script, I can save / download a file with the dictionary in it.
But it gets saved only in the Downloads folder.

```
function myFunction() {
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(dict));
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'dict.json';
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

I want to save it on Django's media folder per user.

media > {{user}} > dict.json

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using local storage? cause i don't think you can use file system in fronted JavaScript.

Comment: create a folder and set "upload_to" to that path, you can also write a function that creates a path if its not already there. You can simply google your question. On a site note: you should not use the media folder for that kind of stuff...

Comment: @MostafaRahmati - I have tried local storage. But that doesn't allow me to save the file locally. I want to save the file at the backend, which is where the media folder will be.

Comment: @hansTheFranz - I've tried that on the views.py file. But that still didn't save a Javascript variable to a file in the media folder. Or maybe I've missed an important step?

Comment: I dont know which steps you took but it is possible. I would suggest a different approach to your problem. Saving and serving a file containing js the user inputs is dangerous. I would use a JSON field to store the values. Validate the input with regex and save them as JSON. It also reduces the load on your media server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using Ajax.

Ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'drawing' user %}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                url: JSON.stringify(dict), // coordinates are saved on dict
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
            success : function(json) {
                alert("Drawing saved!");
            },
            error : function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert("Drawing could not be saved!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

views.py:

```
def drawing(request):
    user = request.user

    url = request.POST.get('url') # url from ajax will be saved here.
    first_value = next(iter(((request.POST).dict()).values())) # cleaning output
    
    with open("media/{}/dict.json".format(user), 'w') as draw:
        draw.write(first_value) # save to file

    return JsonResponse(url, safe=False)
```